# SSL cipher error with curl

Tags: curl, ssl

I am trying to grab a webpage with `curl`

> `$ curl -k https://1.1.1.1/login.html`
>
> curl: (35) error:14092105:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_hello:wrong cipher returned

The error means nothing to me. I have no problem downloading the webpage with `firefox`. How do I go about debugging the issue?

> `$ curl -V`
>
> curl 7.53.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.53.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2k zlib/1.2.11 libpsl/0.17.0 (+libicu/58.2) libssh2/1.8.0
>
> Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
>
> Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL

Comment: http://disablessl3.com

Comment: The server you are trying to access is somewhat broken. Please provide the URL to the server (if it is public) to find out what exactly is broken with it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I didn't make up the 1.1.1.1 ip address :) While it is a public server, it is the wifi authentication gatekeeper so not remotely accessible. Potentially relevant information is that I used to be able to use curl to access the webpage. I am not sure when I last did it and what has been updated since then. The server could also have been updated.

Comment: @StrongBad: if it used to work and still works with a current Firefox try `curl --cipher DES-CBC3-SHA http://...`. It might be that this cipher is disabled by default in your version of curl.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I get *failed setting cipher list*. It looks like I do not have that cipher installed `openssl ciphers -v | grep DES`. I am using Arch.

Comment: @StrongBad: try `ciphers -v 'ALL'` instead. DES-CBC3-SHA is moved out of DEFAULT and into LOW so it will not be shown by default. Also, have a look which cipher Firefox successfully uses with this host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could connect to the server with Firefox, I added the [CipherFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cipherfox/) add-on. This allowed me to determine the cipher used by Firefox when connecting. In my case it was the cipher was TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA. A little Googling led me to a [list of ciphers](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Ciphers(1)) that suggests that TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA is AES256-SHA. I then simply ahd to tell `curl` to use the new cipher

```
curl --ciphers AES256-SHA -k https://1.1.1.1/login.html
```

As this is a public wifi login portal, I am not worried about security. If you are worried about security, you should probably make sure the cipher you are using is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176433/lwp-iosocketssl-fails-with-ssl3-get-server-hellowrong-cipher-returned
You should check SSL, is it using IP or hostname? if it is using hostname best to use hostname instead of IP.

Answer (score 1):

SSL is a complex protocol with many options. The client and the server need to negociate to select compatible options. This is made especially difficult because one of the objectives of SSL is to protect against a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and one of the possible methods of attack is to perturb the negociation — which has to happen before secure communication is established — in order to force insecure parameters.

[SSLv3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#SSL_1.0.2C_2.0_and_3.0) is an obsolete version of the protocol. Today TLS 1.2 is preferred, 1.0 is ok (as is 1.1, but it's rare in practice). If the negociation goes down to SSLv3, either the server is seriously outdated or something went wrong (probably because the server is badly configured).

A useful tool to get more information about what's going on is [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark). Tell it to record TCP traffic to 1.1.1.1 on port 443 with the filter `host 1.1.1.1 and port 443`. Wireshark should automatically detect the connection as SSL and will display a detailed analysis of each message. In the SSL connection, the client first sends a “client hello” message which indicates what settings it supports, and the server replies with a “server hello” that makes a selection among the client's supported settings. Here it seems that the server has selected something that the client doesn't support, causing a protocol downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

curl -d "submit=accept&buttonClicked=4&err_flag=0&network_name=Guest%20Network" --ciphers AES256-SHA -k -X POST https://1.1.1.1/login.html

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to this site. To get to your answer, [please edit your post to include additional context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/489752/edit) How does this answer the question? Please elaborate. Thank you!